# How to pass + read arguments when dealing with | (pipe)?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ubuntu, centos

I'm trying to pass-in the arguments and print it back out. I can't.

## Try #1

```
curl www.site.com/bash/bashrc.sh | bash

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3391  100  3391    0     0  66809      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 67820
There 0 arguments
```

## Try #2

```
curl www.site.com/bash/bashrc.sh | bash yellow red green

bash: yellow: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3391  100  3391    0     0   130k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  132k
(23) Failed writing body
```

---

*My goal is to be able to access my arguments that I passed inside my script : `yellow` ,  `red` , `green`*

[0] : bash

[1] : yellow

[2] : red

[3] : green

---

**bashrc.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@
do echo $i
done

echo "There $# arguments"

....
```

How can I acheive that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-s` switch:

```
curl www.site.com/bash/bashrc.sh | bash -s yellow red green

yellow
red
green
There 3 arguments
```

As per `man bash`:

```
-s  If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing,
    then commands are read from the  standard  input. This  option allows the positional
    parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.
```